# Shrink Row size when content size decreases

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms page with a grid and an editor within the grid.

My Grid definition is...

```
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btmGrid">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

</Grid>
```

When my editor height increases as more text is added it expands as excepted. When text is removed and the editor height decreases, the grid height doesn't decrease - it keeps the max height value it reached while the editor was expanding.

Is there any way to decrease the row height again as the editor height decreases?

Answer (score 0):

I had done a demo to test your code. But the row height will change with the editor height. My code is as following.

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btmGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Editor  Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 AutoSize="TextChanges"
             />
        <Editor  Grid.Column="0"
             Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 AutoSize="TextChanges"
             />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: I've created a sample at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJf8RkTPm5_3QWjoFpA1Ju6IcYY3vvSS/view?usp=sharing - the editor expands but doesn't decrease.